# React router `this.props.history.push` - history not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this logout function:

```
logOut = () => {
    axios
      .delete(`${apiUrl}/logout`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 204) {
          localStorage.removeItem('key', response.headers.authorization)
          localStorage.removeItem('id', response.data.id)
          // return <Redirect to="/login" />
          this.props.history.push(`/login`)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

`this.props.history.push('/something')` works on every other occasion. But here it says cannot read `push` of undefined.  I tried `return <Redirect to="/login" />` which doesn't work too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Curry your component with the "withRouter" method from the React-router-dom library.  Include this at the top of your js file: `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom`.  Include this where you're exporting your component: `export default withRouter(MyComponent)`.  This will allow you to access the history prop in your component.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It may because of one of these reasons:

1- You need to pass your component to withRouter when you are using history.push:

```
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom

   // ... codes of component in here ...

    export default withRouter(componentName) // at the end of component
```

2- *this* is referring to axios and you need to define this over the axios with another name and use it in axios e.g.:

```
var that = this;

 // then use that in axios
```

Comment: Is it exist on console.log(this.props) ?

Comment: Apparently it was a cache problem, `withRouter` works now.